# svn checkout with sub directories in google code error?

Tags: svn, google-code

I am attempting to checkout some code with svn.

This is the command I'm using:

```
svn checkout http://xssm.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/commons-lib/WordNet/3.0/ xssm-read-only
```

I am able to access the sub sub directory(/commons-lib/WordNet/3.0) as seen here: http://code.google.com/p/xssm/source/browse/trunk/commons-lib/WordNet/?r=151#WordNet%2F3.0

Why can I access that sub directory structure, but it is not available when I try to checkout?

This is the error I get: svn: URL 'http://xssm.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/commons-lib/WordNet/3.0' doesn't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am able to access the sub sub directory(/commons-lib/WordNet/3.0) as seen here

This is URL for old, historical revision, not HEAD. And this URL doesn't exist **now**

> svn ls http://xssm.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/commons-lib/WordNet
>
> 2.0/

compare with this URL and output

> svn ls http://xssm.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/commons-lib/WordNet@151
>
> 3.0/

In order to checkout this old revision, you have to add [PEG-revision](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html) to URL

`svn checkout http://xssm.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/commons-lib/WordNet/3.0@151 xssm-read-only`

Comment: So would there be a way to checkout all the files in the 3.0 directory?